# On Error print previous actual and next record

Tags: awk

In the following example, in column 2. values are increasing, Then the purpose is to get records which are not in increase order and print ( previous - error - next )

**file**

```
2343 290232732   
2343 290232738   
2349 290202757   
2342 290232758   
2343 290232813   
2341 291063213   
2343 291043555   
2345 291063609   
2343 291063622   
2343 291063637   
2341 291053637   
2343 291063702   
2343 291063707   
2343 291063712   
2343 291063751
```

**I tried**

```
awk '{                                                                                                                               
         if(substr($0,6,9) < prev -1)                                                                                                                        
         {printf ("** ERROR ** %4d --> %4d --> %4d\n",prv2, prev, substr($0,6,9)) } ; prv2 = prev; prev = substr($0,6,9)}'  file
```

How I can add ; **exit 1** to the code in order to stop the process after the last error are found.

**I got**

```
** ERROR ** 290232732 --> 290232738 --> 290202757
** ERROR ** 290232813 --> 291063213 --> 291043555
** ERROR ** 291063622 --> 291063637 --> 291053637
```

**Desired Output**

```
** ERROR ** 290232738 --> 290202757 --> 290232758
** ERROR ** 291063213 --> 291043555 --> 291063609
** ERROR ** 291063637 --> 291053637 --> 291063702
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think there is any way to know when is the last error without going through the whole file at least once.

Comment: jas, tks, in that case will be enough to get the errors as desired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this awk :

```
awk '
  f {                           # if flag print ERROR
    p = p FS "-->" FS $2
    print "** ERROR **" FS p
    split ( p , a )             # keep $2 of previous line in p
    p = a[3]                    # this way if it is in error you can catch it
    f = 0                       # remove flag
  }
  $2 > p {                      # $2 is ok keep it
    p = $2
    next
  }
  {
    p = p FS "-->" FS $2        # $2 is not ok
    f = 1                       # prepare to print
  }
  END {
    if ( f )                    # the last line is in error
      print "** ERROR **" FS p  # print it
  }
' file
```

Comment: hi ctac, the code works, but always prints the last line of file? also it considers as error if the previous value is the same as the actual..?.. Kindly can you fix it. Tks

Comment: If the previous value is the same as the actual, it's not in increase order. You can change the line $2 > p by $2 >= p. 'always prints the last line of file?' sorry, I don't understand. $2 of last line is printed only if last line is in error or previous last line is in error.

Comment: Hi catc, tks for the code and explanation, sorry for 'always prints the last line of file' in my file i had 2 extra empty lines at the end of file, that was the reason the code prints it.. But it is Ok now. Tks a lot